# webpack ReferenceError:window is not defined

Tags: javascript, web, webpack

I am currently trying to set up webpack.
My project is a single page website, and my currrent webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

when i am trying to run webpack i get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Subversion\Cloud\trunk
    at __webpack_require__ (c:\Subversion\Cloud\trun
    at c:\Subversion\Cloud\trunk\Web\Servicebericht\
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Subversion\Cloud\trunk
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
```

The only topics i found to this are when someone used loader, which i havent configured yet, so i don't think this is my problem.

What do i need to do, to get webpack to recognize window?